# SSRS IIF condition is giving empty values

Tags: reporting-services

I have one column with 7 possible values, I wanted to eliminate the rows with a value equal to '5' at the table.

When I used IIF condition like:

```
iif(Value<>"5",Value,Nothing)
```

However it is still giving me the values with empty rows.

Can you please tell me how to hide the rows with '5' as value?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking.  Are you trying to replace the values that show "5" with a blank cell?  Are you trying to remove these records altogether.  Are you trying to remove the first 5 values from the 7 values.  An example with more detail would help with what you have for data, what your expression is, and what your desired outcome will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to remove/hide the entire rows that don't meet this expression, you'll want to define it as a `Filter` in the Tablix Properties or as an expression  for `Row Visibility`.
You'll also might have to change your expression slightly to look more like this:

```
=Iif(Fields!MyColumn.Value <> "5", False, True)
```

or

```
=Iif(Fields!MyColumn.Value = "5", True, False)
```